# Get current location (city name) without gps and mobile network

Tags: dictionary, networking, gps, location, wifi

I have an android tablet that does not hasve a SIM card and GPS set to save battery mode too.
Tablet is connected to the internet by ethernet (with cable) and connected to LAN by WIFI.
I write a code for find current location (city name) and it work good in my phone. (GPS of my phone is active and connected to the internet by wifi (modem) or mobile network).

```java
    package com.xenon.location;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final Activity mActivity;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;

    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Activity activity) {
        this.mContext = activity.getBaseContext();
        this.mActivity = activity;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            //locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
              // no network provider is enabled
            }else{
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            mActivity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity
                                , new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}
                                , 0);
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        0);
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            }
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        String result = "";
        if (location != null) {
            double latitude, longitude;
            List<Address> list;
            Locale locale = new Locale("tr");
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext, locale);
            try {
                list = geocoder.getFromLocation(getLatitude(), getLongitude(), 2);

                Address address = list.get(0);

    /*
                String gpsMsg = "CountryCode: " + address.getCountryCode() +
                        " ,AdminArea : " + address.getAdminArea() +
                        " ,CountryName : " + address.getCountryName() +
                        " ,SubLocality : " + address.getSubLocality();
    */
                result = address.getAdminArea();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    }
```

when run it on Tablet :

```
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

isNetworkEnabled and canGetLocation always return false;

Answer (score 1):

You can't get location because you disable the GPS.
but if you want to get your location without GPS, try to get the CELL INFORMATION(MNC MCC CELLID AND LAC) where your device Connected then try to USE API (unwiredlab.com) to convert that Cell INFO into location.

Comment: ok. thanks. i wll research about "get the CELL INFORMATION(MNC MCC CELLID AND LAC)"

Comment: My device only has a LAN connection and is connected to the Internet via LAN